# DarkGDK, make a gap between sprite spawn times

Tags: c++, sprite, delay, gdk

I have a for loop in which I declare positions of sprites. But they usually get spawned near each other and it looks horrible. Using such functions as `dbWait(1000);` freezes all the sprites with it so it's not a solution.

Is there a way to make a gap between spawning?

```
for(int i=20;i<=25;i++){
    dbSprite(i,dbRnd(500),dbRnd(90)+400,20);
    dbHideSprite(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int spritesToSpawn = 25;

while (LoopGDK ())
{
 if (spritesToSpawn)
  if (waitToSpawn <= 0)
  {
    dbSprite (i, dbRnd (500), dbRnd(90)_400, 20);
    waitToSpawn = SPAWNING_DELAY;
    --spritesToSpawn;
  }
  else
    --waitToSpawn;

 ...

 dbSync();
}
```

That is, the trick is to make use of that main loop.  Let it go about its business, making use of it to spawn whenever you're ready for another.